# TWIG: What is wrong with this recursive iteration

Tags: php, twig

I've made a recursive function in TWIG using a macro. This macro is supposed to count how many times it can find description in a nested array and return this.

Can anbody help me in solving what's going wrong. The fiddle can be found at:

https://twigfiddle.com/5uskoi

The result as you can see there is 4 while it should be 6.

Thanks for your time!

Regards,
Jasper

the TWIG code:

```
{% macro countArray(item) %}
  {% import _self as self %}

    {% set total = 1 %}

    {% for yesItem in item.yes.items %}
      {% set total = total + self.countArray(yesItem) %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for noItem in item.no.items %}
      {% set total = + total + self.countArray(noItem) %}
    {% endfor %}

    {{ total }}

{% endmacro %}

{% from _self import countArray %}

{% for item in data.items %}

    {{ countArray(item) }}    

{% endfor %}
```

with this data:

```
data:
    items:                    
        - description: '1'
          yes:
              items:
                  - description: '2'
                  - description: '3'
          no:
              items:                    
                  - description: '4'
                    yes:
                        items:
                            - description: '5'
                            - description: '6'
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to this problem. I have added |trim after the macro call. This trims all the whitespace and other stuff that got returned with the number.

This caused the problem of adding them together.

The twigfiddle has been updated with this settings for further reference!

Regards,
Jasper